# What are the different possible ways of updating content on a website for all users from one account

Tags: database, admin, dashboard

I have a project i will be taking on for a client in the future that would require me to make a system where they can update content on the webpage from an admin account, example being like a welcome message or information that would change regularly. I understand one way this could be achieved would be by getting the information from a database and then updating it etc which would work perfectly but i wanted to know if there are other ways to do something like this without using a content management system like WordPress. Thank you in advance and youll have to forgive me if this is a bad question i dont post often.

I will try the approach that i know off which is updating the messages in a database unless there is a more efficient way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about the project requirement, costs, your skills, if you have programming skills.

If you have enough time to develop a solution, you have enough programming skills to overcome technical issues, your project requirements may change over time, and you may need something more than available `CMS` systems.

As a bare-bone approach you can put everything in Configuration files. for example you can use `xml` files to store your webpage construction info (like welcome message, localization, setting titles and captions and ....).

You can update those files whenever the admin wanted. This way you should keep track of those files. you should prevent of having a large number of config files. huge number of config file throws you in troubles.

databases on the other hand provide centralized information storage. configuration is a piece of information by the way.

Using database you gain better performance vs config files. because of the fact that your configurations are limited number of records so it will help you by caching them in memory for faster access. instead of loading files and knowing that you should take care of concurrency issues.

Comment: Thank you this did answer my question. I'll have a look into those things you mentioned